# Returns rows where the grouping a column returns more than one unique values in another column

Tags: pandas

Alright, so I'm trying to merge some fairly messy databases. I have a column of gvkeys that I matched with permnos. Some of the gvkeys were matched with more than one permno so I'm trying to look at the instances where this happened.

I've got something that looks like this:

```
 df.groupby('gvkey').LPERMNO.nunique() > 1
```

which gets me a series that has "true" next to all the gvkeys I'm interested in.

I'm hoping to run something like

```
 gvkeys = df.groupby('gvkey').LPERMNO.nunique() > 1

 df.loc(gvkey in gvkeys)
```

but clearly that's not quite right. Thanks in adavance for your help!

Comment: `df[df.groupby('gvkey').LPERMNO.transform('nunique') > 1]`  should work.

Comment: That's the ticket. Thanks!